# Strange iOS Keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios9, uikeyboard

I am working on an app, and every now and then my keyboard starts acting strangely (see screenshot below). The keyboard isn't a custom keyboard, it's just using the dark appearance. I know there have been issues reported about keyboard issues on iOS 9, but I cannot find any of them.

Does anyone know what would cause this or have links acknowledging this is a known bug?

Thanks in advanced for the help.

[image: strange ios keyboard]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming; try apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I believe this is a known bug in iOS 9, it happens in apps such as Tweetbot, however I haven't seen it for a while on iOS 9.2. I doubt there is anything wrong with your code that is related to this :)